# C++ - std::map.insert() segmentation fault

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, insert, segmentation-fault

I get a segmentation fault when i try to insert into my map.

The function looks something like this:

```
void add(std::string id, std::string name)
{
Asset asset(nullptr, false, name);
mAssets.insert(std::make_pair<std::string, Asset>(id,asset)); <-- This line gives segfault
}
```

mAssets is simply declared

```
std::map<assetID, Asset> mAssets;
```

And the Asset class is (sloppy) declared like this:

```
class Asset
{
public:
   Asset(T* a, bool l, std::string f) : asset(a), loaded(l), filename(f)
    {
    }
  Asset(const Asset& copy) 
{
  loaded   = copy.loaded;
  filename = copy.filename;
  asset    = new T();
  *asset   = *copy.asset;
}
  ~Asset()
{
  delete asset;
}
  Asset& operator=(const Asset& other)
{
  Asset temp(other);
  loaded = temp.loaded;
  filename = temp.filename;
  std::swap(asset,temp.asset);
  return *this;
}

  T*          asset;
  bool        loaded;
  std::string filename;
};
```

Comment: What's your assetId key class?

Comment: assetID is a typedeffed std::string

Comment: Generally to make code more readable (for me, at least), I prefer: `mAssets[id] = asset;`

Comment: You sometimes put nullptr into asset (e.g. in the function that's crashing) - consider what will happen when *asset = *copy.asset runs....  You should handle the nullptr case in the copy constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is here in your copy constructor:

```
  asset    = new T();
  *asset   = *copy.asset;
```

I will leave it to you to work out why...

Comment: then your problem is elsewhere (at least not in the code you've put up...)

Comment: I have narrowed it down to that specific line, code seems to work on my laptop running ubuntu but not on this Solaris computer..

Comment: then run up the debugger and see exactly where it fails - it should take you less time than waiting for us to guess(?)

Comment: sorry for the stupid question, but how do i run the debugger? its my first time developing on this platform, im using emacs and gcc

Comment: check that your platform has `gdb` installed, then run `gdb <name of binary>`, then `run` at the prompt. As to how to use gdb (GNU Debugger), use your favourite search engine for a quick tutorial, it will only take 10 mins or so...

Answer (score 1):

On your copy constructor you are derefferencing a null pointer:

```
*asset = *copy.asset
```

from

```
Asset asset(nullptr, false, name);
```

Verify your pointers asigments and avoid dereferencing null pointers:

```
Asset(const Asset& copy) 
{
    loaded   = copy.loaded;
    filename = copy.filename;
    if (copy.asset)
    {
        asset    = new T();   // better may be asset = new T(copy)
        *asset   = *copy.asset;
    }
    else
    {
        asset = nullptr
    } 
}
```

Comment: That still dont fixes the crash

Comment: did you tryed to check pointer deletion on destruction???? In some platforms, like Linux and most unix, you can't delete a null pointer. Review all your pointers dereferencing

Comment: fixed that, still no luck. im running solaris btw

Comment: @TioPepe, I'm not sure about that statement, AFAIK, the standard says that calling `delete` on a `nullptr` should end up doing nothing...

Answer (score 0):

*asset   = *copy.asset; //you should check whether asset is NULL or not then check for asset

This is how  your code will work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
class Asset
{
  public:
    Asset(T* a, bool l, std::string f) : asset(a), loaded(l), filename(f)
  {
  }
    Asset(const Asset& copy) 
    {
      cout<<"copy"<<endl;
      loaded   = copy.loaded;
      filename = copy.filename;
      asset    = new T();
      if(&copy != NULL)
      {
      if(copy.asset != NULL)
        *asset   = *(copy.asset);
      }
    }
    ~Asset()
    {
      delete asset;
    }
    Asset& operator=(const Asset& other)
    {
      Asset temp(other);
      loaded = temp.loaded;
      filename = temp.filename;
      std::swap(asset,temp.asset);
      return *this;
    }

    T*          asset;
    bool        loaded;
    std::string filename;
};

std::map <string,Asset<int> > mAssets;

void add(std::string id, std::string name)
{
  Asset<int> asset(NULL, false, name);
  mAssets.insert(std::make_pair<std::string, Asset<int> >(id,asset)); //<-- This line gives segfault
}


int main()
{
  add("1","hi");
  cout<<"run"<<endl;

}
```

Comment: what is the purpose of this -> `if(&copy != NULL)`

Comment: if(&copy != NULL) could be removed, but before copying data pointers should be checked if they are pointing valid data to ensure copy constructor works.